# What is a base initializer in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

My teacher asked me what a base initializer in C++ is.
Can someone of you provide me a definition?

Comment: Is he still waiting for an answer ?

Comment: I have time until thursday.

Comment: Did you check before that your teacher doesn't have a `stackoverflow` account?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38tx22fy.aspx

Comment: it takes 0.01 second to google it

Comment: What a silly question. A base initializer is one that's made out of lead instead of gold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on: Initialiser Lists.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html